# 2 diferent versions of gcc in RHEL

Tags: rhel5, gcc

I need to test a matlab EDA-LINK with Cadence Incisive.

For this , one of the libraries complains of an error:
version `GCC_3.3' not found (required by/appli/cadence/IUS82_ISR11/tools/lib/libstdc++.so.6

this is EZ, its because my installed version is newer ...

gcc -v : GCC  is version 3.4.6..

What should i do ?? 
-can i install 2 diferent versions of GCC @ the same time ??
-should i ask for a library for my compiler to the provider??
- can i downgrade gcc ???  does this have effects over installed programs??

Thanks for the help !!!